I want to define h function in pytorch based module however i have problem when defining it with the tensors and batches
This h function is actually measurement function in extended kalman filter. I want to convert this h function so that i can use it in KalmanNet(Neural Network & EKF hybrid). I have done some convertion however i am not sure whether my h function is well defined? This is h function in KalmanNet:
 def h(State_est):
    State_est = State_est.float()  # Ensure State_est is float32

    num_sensors_x = 4
    num_sensors_y = 4
    
    num_sensors = num_sensors_x * num_sensors_y
    sensor_coords = np.array([[x, y] for x in np.linspace(0, 40, num_sensors_x) for y in np.linspace(0, 40, num_sensors_y)])
    sensor_coords = torch.tensor(sensor_coords, dtype=torch.float32, device=State_est.device)
    
    # Initialize tensor for predicted measurements
    PredMeasurements = torch.zeros((State_est.shape[0], num_sensors), dtype=torch.float32, device=State_est.device)
    P0 = torch.tensor(1000, dtype=torch.float32, device=State_est.device)

    for i in range(State_est.shape[0]):  # Iterate over batch
        th = 5
        for j in range(num_sensors):
            x_i, y_i = sensor_coords[j]
            d_i_t = torch.sqrt((x_i - State_est[i, 0])**2 + (y_i - State_est[i, 1])**2)
            z_t = P0 / (1 + d_i_t**2)
            PredMeasurements[i, j] = z_t

    # Add an extra dimension to match expected shape [batch_size, num_features, 1]
    PredMeasurements = torch.unsqueeze(PredMeasurements, 2)
    #print(PredMeasurements)
    return PredMeasurements

Thank you so much in advance
I expected a nice tracking for my code however it does not track the object well. I think it is because of h function is not defined well for the pytorch case.

I suspect that your question is too broad to get a useful answer here. I skimmed over the function and nothing is obviously wrong (thought your th value is unused). I'm not sure what you mean when you say that your function is "not defined well". You probably need to do some troubleshooting with the rest of your code.
